# Problem with Module, Function, Association and Dataset

Tags: warning-messages, dataset, scoping, associations, map

I have struck a combination of the above-mentioned functions that causes evaluation to fail. I wonder whether someone can help me create a more minimal example in order to understand the issue better.

Assuming the definitions:

```
dataset1 = Dataset@<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>;
dataset2 = Dataset@<|"c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>;
datasets = {dataset1, dataset2};
assoc1 = <|"aa" -> 8, "cc" -> 9|>;
test1[in1_] := in1
test2[in1_, in2_] := {in1, in2}
```

We can pass in that list of datasets to a Module that passes them, one by one, into another Module that calls a function on it:

```
Map[Function[localDataset, Module[{},
    Normal@Map[Function[localDatasetEntries, test1[localDatasetEntries]], localDataset]
  ]], datasets]
(* {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>} *)
```

Upon switching the interior function to one that also uses the globally-defined association, it no longer works:

```
Map[Function[localDataset, Module[{},
   Normal@Map[Function[localDatasetEntries,test2[localDatasetEntries, assoc1]], localDataset]
   ]], datasets]
(* MapAt::partw: Part {All,2} of <|aa->8,cc->9|> does not exist. 
MapAt::partw: Part {All,2} of <|aa->8,cc->9|> does not exist.
{$Failed, $Failed} *)
```

although care should be taken because once the above statements have been passed once to the kernel, the evaluation does work. Assuming a new kernel, running the above statement twice gives:

```
Map[Function[localDataset, Module[{},
   Normal@Map[Function[localDatasetEntries, test2[localDatasetEntries, assoc1]], localDataset]
   ]], datasets]
Map[Function[localDataset, Module[{},
   Normal@Map[Function[localDatasetEntries, test2[localDatasetEntries, assoc1]], localDataset]
   ]], datasets]
(* MapAt::partw: Part {All,2} of <|aa->8,cc->9|> does not exist.
MapAt::partw: Part {All,2} of <|aa->8,cc->9|> does not exist.
{$Failed, $Failed}
{<|"a" -> {1, <|"aa" -> 8, "cc" -> 9|>}, "b" -> {2, <|"aa" -> 8, "cc" -> 9|>}|>, <|"c" -> {3, <|"aa" -> 8, "cc" -> 9|>}, "d" -> {4, <|"aa" -> 8, "cc" -> 9|>}|>} *)
```

Further, assuming a new kernel each time, certain ways to insert Normal[] into the expression solve the problem; others don't. This one works:

```
Map[Function[localDataset, Module[{},
    Normal@Map[Function[localDatasetEntries, test2[localDatasetEntries, assoc1]], Normal@localDataset]
   ]], datasets]
(* {{"a" -> {1, <|"aa" -> 8, "cc" -> 9|>}, "b" -> {2, <|"aa" -> 8, "cc" -> 9|>}}, {"c" -> {3, <|"aa" -> 8, "cc" -> 9|>}, "d" -> {4, <|"aa" -> 8, "cc" -> 9|>}}} *)
```

and this one does not:

```
Map[Function[localDataset, Module[{},
    Normal@Map[Function[localDatasetEntries,test2[Normal@localDatasetEntries, assoc1]], localDataset]
   ]], datasets]
(* MapAt::partw: Part {All,2} of <|aa->8,cc->9|> does not exist. 
MapAt::partw: Part {All,2} of <|aa->8,cc->9|> does not exist.
{$Failed, $Failed} *)
```

My particular issue is that I have partitioned a rather large dataset into smaller groups with some shared values, and I would like to operate one by one on the entries in each subgroup, using a list of globally-defined associations as parameters.

My question is, why is this happening? Why do some computations with structured datasets fail while their "normal" association forms work fine? Should we expect to generally encounter this type of issue in certain particular cases? Is there a general fix?

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem, but I think you suffer from some misunderstanding about what `Module` and especially `Print` do: `Print` will print its argument to the notebook but return `Null`, and most errors you see are due to that. `Module` with an empty list of local variables is a noop, so you could just remove it without any change in what the code does...

Comment: Removing Print[] and Module[] has no effect. I removed them above for clarity. (Also removed a typo semicolon that was causing a Null output, thanks.)

Comment: So what is your goal: do you want to append `assoc1` to both datasets as shown as a list?

Comment: In my actual code project, the nested Modules are serving a purpose, localizing the scope of other calculations. Removing them entirely makes everything work, but my question is about why they won't work in this case.

Comment: @gwr Yes, I'd like to operate locally on the entries of each dataset - appending the association to the existing dataset is the most basic example I could think of.

Comment: @gwr Edited so hopefully my question is clearer. (Why isn't the assumption that if the question isn't explicitly stated, it can be assumed to be "why is this happening"?)

Comment: Could someone please explain why people keep taking away their upvotes on this question? I continue to have this problem and I can't always fix it with the one answer provided so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure why this is happening, but a quick solution is to wrap `Association` around `assoc1`. So this (using the OP's) example will work out without any error messages:

```
Map[ 
    Function[ localDataset, Module[ {}, 
       Normal @ Map[  
           Function[ localDatasetEntries, 
               test2[ localDatasetEntries, Association[assoc1] ] 
           ], 
           localDataset
       ]
      ]
    ], 
    datasets
]
```

> {<|"a" -> {1, <|"aa" -> 8, "cc" -> 9|>}, 
>     "b" -> {2, <|"aa" -> 8, "cc" -> 9|>}|>, <|"c" -> {3, <|"aa" -> 8, 
>        "cc" -> 9|>}, "d" -> {4, <|"aa" -> 8, "cc" -> 9|>}|>}

But those `Module`, `Map`, `Function` and `Normal` *concoctions* look like the "*most ugly code*" I have seen in a long time :) So note, that something in this line will work (and may also be localized imo):

```
With[
    {assoc = assoc1},
    Dataset@datasets // Query[ All, All, List[#, Association[assoc]] & ]
]
```

[image: datasets]

Comment: @ninemileskid Does this help?

Comment: Yes, it does. Using Association[assoc1] is slightly slower than using the version with Normal in my original post, despite it preserving the Dataset heads - but it does work. It seems the Query solution sometimes takes an excessively long time to finish, although other times it is just as fast as the others. (It seems to do this most often upon a freshly started kernel.)